# Using logrotate with syslog-ng on raspberry pi (how to delete old logs?)

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, logrotate, syslog-ng

Ok..

I'm using my raspberry pi as a syslog server for a Cisco ASA and a Cisco router.

I have the logs being populated to my /var/log/network destination.  They are currently being logged with the format: _$MONTH$DAY$YEAR.log, with ROUTER or FIREWALL as the device.

So far its working great!  I'm getting logs broken out by day for both my router and my firewall.  Problem is that I'm getting pretty big logs...pretty fast because of the ASA.

I'm new to logrotate..so this is what I have so far:

In my /etc/logrotate.d/syslog-ng directory...

```
    /var/log/network/*.log*
   { 
    rotate 5
   }
```

For the global options in the logrotate.conf file:

```
admin@kylespi:/etc$ more logrotate.conf
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# no packages own wtmp, or btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
missingok
monthly
create 0664 root utmp
rotate 1
}

/var/log/btmp {
missingok
monthly
create 0660 root utmp
rotate 1
}
```

Now...if I try to force logrotate to run:

```
sudo logrotate /etc/logrotate.d -v
```

Instead of deleting the files older than 5 days (based on the rotate 5 command)..I get this:

```
admin@kylespi:/etc$ sudo ls /var/log/network
FIREWALL_03052014.log              FIREWALL_03072014.log                  FIREWALL_03092014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1  FIREWALL_03122014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1
FIREWALL_03052014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1  FIREWALL_03072014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1      FIREWALL_03102014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1  ROUTER_03082014.log
FIREWALL_03062014.log              FIREWALL_03082014.log                  FIREWALL_03112014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1
```

FIREWALL_03062014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1  FIREWALL_03082014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1  FIREWALL_03122014.log

If it helps, the output from the "logrotate /etc/logrotate.d -v" command says the following:

```
admin@kylespi:/etc/logrotate.d$ sudo logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/syslog-ng -v
[sudo] password for admin: 
reading config file /etc/logrotate.d/syslog-ng

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /var/log/network/*.log*
 1048576 bytes (5 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03052014.log
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03052014.log.1.1.1.1.1
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03062014.log
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03062014.log.1.1.1.1.1
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03072014.log
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03072014.log.1.1.1.1.1
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03082014.log
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03082014.log.1.1.1.1.1
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03092014.log.1.1.1.1.1
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03102014.log.1.1.1.1.1
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03112014.log.1.1.1.1.1
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03122014.log
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03122014.log.1.1.1.1.1
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/network/ROUTER_03082014.log
  log does not need rotating
rotating log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03052014.log.1.1.1.1.1, log->rotateCount is 5
dateext suffix '-20140312'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03052014.log.1.1.1.1.1.5 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03052014.log.1.1.1.1.1.6 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 5), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03052014.log.1.1.1.1.1.5 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03052014.log.1.1.1.1.1.4 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03052014.log.1.1.1.1.1.5 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 4), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03052014.log.1.1.1.1.1.4 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03052014.log.1.1.1.1.1.3 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03052014.log.1.1.1.1.1.4 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 3), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03052014.log.1.1.1.1.1.3 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03052014.log.1.1.1.1.1.2 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03052014.log.1.1.1.1.1.3 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 2), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03052014.log.1.1.1.1.1.2 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03052014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03052014.log.1.1.1.1.1.2 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 1), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03052014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03052014.log.1.1.1.1.1.0 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03052014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 0), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03052014.log.1.1.1.1.1.0 does not exist
log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03052014.log.1.1.1.1.1.6 doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03052014.log.1.1.1.1.1 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03052014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1
rotating log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03062014.log.1.1.1.1.1, log->rotateCount is 5
dateext suffix '-20140312'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03062014.log.1.1.1.1.1.5 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03062014.log.1.1.1.1.1.6 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 5), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03062014.log.1.1.1.1.1.5 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03062014.log.1.1.1.1.1.4 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03062014.log.1.1.1.1.1.5 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 4), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03062014.log.1.1.1.1.1.4 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03062014.log.1.1.1.1.1.3 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03062014.log.1.1.1.1.1.4 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 3), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03062014.log.1.1.1.1.1.3 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03062014.log.1.1.1.1.1.2 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03062014.log.1.1.1.1.1.3 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 2), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03062014.log.1.1.1.1.1.2 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03062014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03062014.log.1.1.1.1.1.2 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 1), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03062014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03062014.log.1.1.1.1.1.0 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03062014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 0), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03062014.log.1.1.1.1.1.0 does not exist
log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03062014.log.1.1.1.1.1.6 doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03062014.log.1.1.1.1.1 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03062014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1
rotating log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03072014.log.1.1.1.1.1, log->rotateCount is 5
dateext suffix '-20140312'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03072014.log.1.1.1.1.1.5 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03072014.log.1.1.1.1.1.6 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 5), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03072014.log.1.1.1.1.1.5 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03072014.log.1.1.1.1.1.4 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03072014.log.1.1.1.1.1.5 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 4), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03072014.log.1.1.1.1.1.4 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03072014.log.1.1.1.1.1.3 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03072014.log.1.1.1.1.1.4 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 3), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03072014.log.1.1.1.1.1.3 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03072014.log.1.1.1.1.1.2 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03072014.log.1.1.1.1.1.3 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 2), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03072014.log.1.1.1.1.1.2 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03072014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03072014.log.1.1.1.1.1.2 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 1), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03072014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03072014.log.1.1.1.1.1.0 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03072014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 0), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03072014.log.1.1.1.1.1.0 does not exist
log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03072014.log.1.1.1.1.1.6 doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03072014.log.1.1.1.1.1 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03072014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1
rotating log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03082014.log.1.1.1.1.1, log->rotateCount is 5
dateext suffix '-20140312'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03082014.log.1.1.1.1.1.5 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03082014.log.1.1.1.1.1.6 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 5), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03082014.log.1.1.1.1.1.5 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03082014.log.1.1.1.1.1.4 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03082014.log.1.1.1.1.1.5 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 4), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03082014.log.1.1.1.1.1.4 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03082014.log.1.1.1.1.1.3 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03082014.log.1.1.1.1.1.4 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 3), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03082014.log.1.1.1.1.1.3 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03082014.log.1.1.1.1.1.2 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03082014.log.1.1.1.1.1.3 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 2), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03082014.log.1.1.1.1.1.2 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03082014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03082014.log.1.1.1.1.1.2 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 1), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03082014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03082014.log.1.1.1.1.1.0 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03082014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 0), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03082014.log.1.1.1.1.1.0 does not exist
log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03082014.log.1.1.1.1.1.6 doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03082014.log.1.1.1.1.1 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03082014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1
rotating log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03092014.log.1.1.1.1.1, log->rotateCount is 5
dateext suffix '-20140312'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03092014.log.1.1.1.1.1.5 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03092014.log.1.1.1.1.1.6 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 5), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03092014.log.1.1.1.1.1.5 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03092014.log.1.1.1.1.1.4 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03092014.log.1.1.1.1.1.5 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 4), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03092014.log.1.1.1.1.1.4 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03092014.log.1.1.1.1.1.3 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03092014.log.1.1.1.1.1.4 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 3), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03092014.log.1.1.1.1.1.3 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03092014.log.1.1.1.1.1.2 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03092014.log.1.1.1.1.1.3 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 2), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03092014.log.1.1.1.1.1.2 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03092014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03092014.log.1.1.1.1.1.2 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 1), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03092014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03092014.log.1.1.1.1.1.0 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03092014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 0), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03092014.log.1.1.1.1.1.0 does not exist
log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03092014.log.1.1.1.1.1.6 doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03092014.log.1.1.1.1.1 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03092014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1
rotating log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03102014.log.1.1.1.1.1, log->rotateCount is 5
dateext suffix '-20140312'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03102014.log.1.1.1.1.1.5 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03102014.log.1.1.1.1.1.6 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 5), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03102014.log.1.1.1.1.1.5 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03102014.log.1.1.1.1.1.4 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03102014.log.1.1.1.1.1.5 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 4), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03102014.log.1.1.1.1.1.4 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03102014.log.1.1.1.1.1.3 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03102014.log.1.1.1.1.1.4 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 3), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03102014.log.1.1.1.1.1.3 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03102014.log.1.1.1.1.1.2 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03102014.log.1.1.1.1.1.3 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 2), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03102014.log.1.1.1.1.1.2 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03102014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03102014.log.1.1.1.1.1.2 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 1), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03102014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03102014.log.1.1.1.1.1.0 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03102014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 0), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03102014.log.1.1.1.1.1.0 does not exist
log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03102014.log.1.1.1.1.1.6 doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03102014.log.1.1.1.1.1 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03102014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1
rotating log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03112014.log.1.1.1.1.1, log->rotateCount is 5
dateext suffix '-20140312'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03112014.log.1.1.1.1.1.5 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03112014.log.1.1.1.1.1.6 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 5), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03112014.log.1.1.1.1.1.5 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03112014.log.1.1.1.1.1.4 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03112014.log.1.1.1.1.1.5 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 4), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03112014.log.1.1.1.1.1.4 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03112014.log.1.1.1.1.1.3 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03112014.log.1.1.1.1.1.4 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 3), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03112014.log.1.1.1.1.1.3 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03112014.log.1.1.1.1.1.2 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03112014.log.1.1.1.1.1.3 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 2), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03112014.log.1.1.1.1.1.2 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03112014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03112014.log.1.1.1.1.1.2 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 1), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03112014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03112014.log.1.1.1.1.1.0 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03112014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 0), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03112014.log.1.1.1.1.1.0 does not exist
log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03112014.log.1.1.1.1.1.6 doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03112014.log.1.1.1.1.1 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03112014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1
rotating log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03122014.log.1.1.1.1.1, log->rotateCount is 5
dateext suffix '-20140312'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03122014.log.1.1.1.1.1.5 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03122014.log.1.1.1.1.1.6 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 5), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03122014.log.1.1.1.1.1.5 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03122014.log.1.1.1.1.1.4 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03122014.log.1.1.1.1.1.5 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 4), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03122014.log.1.1.1.1.1.4 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03122014.log.1.1.1.1.1.3 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03122014.log.1.1.1.1.1.4 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 3), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03122014.log.1.1.1.1.1.3 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03122014.log.1.1.1.1.1.2 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03122014.log.1.1.1.1.1.3 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 2), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03122014.log.1.1.1.1.1.2 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03122014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03122014.log.1.1.1.1.1.2 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 1), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03122014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1 does not exist
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03122014.log.1.1.1.1.1.0 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03122014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 0), 
old log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03122014.log.1.1.1.1.1.0 does not exist
log /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03122014.log.1.1.1.1.1.6 doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
renaming /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03122014.log.1.1.1.1.1 to /var/log/network/FIREWALL_03122014.log.1.1.1.1.1.1
```

Comment: Maybe you'd get an answer on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the trailing asterisk:

From

```
/var/log/network/*.log*
```

To

```
/var/log/network/*.log
```